# Flutter integration test: widget is disposed but WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback is still called

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue with my integration test with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` and . Here is my code

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final _myWidgetBloc = MyWidgetBloc();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      _myWidgetBloc.add(Initial(field: fieldValue));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _myWidgetBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  ...
}
```

Then I create an integration test with

```
testWidgets(
    'sign up',
    (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
    },
  );
```

The initialRoute of `MyApp` is pointing to `MyWidget`.

When I run the integration test, I got the following error

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown running a test (but after the test had completed):
Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#1      Bloc.add (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:100:24)
#2      _MyWidgetState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:my_app/pages/my_widget.dart:46:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from dart:async)
```

If I remove the `_myWidgetBloc.close();` in `void dispose()` function, then the error will not happen. I guess my `_myWidgetBloc` is disposed before the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` function is called.

Can I please get some advice on it? Thank you